# Can you use "where" to require an attribute in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, constraints, where-clause

I want to make a generic class that accepts only serializable classes, can it be done with the where constraint?

The concept I'm looking for is this:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : //[is serializable/has the serializable attribute]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid not. The only things you can do with constraints are:

- `where T : class` - T must be a reference type
- `where T : struct` - T must be a non-nullable value type
- `where T : SomeClass` - T must be SomeClass or derive from it
- `where T : ISomeInterface` - T must be ISomeInterface or implement it
- `where T : new()` - T must have a public parameterless constructor

Various combinations are feasible, but not all. Nothing about attributes.

Comment: would `where T : ISerializable` not do it?

Comment: @user457104: That wouldn't force the attribute to be applied, no.

Answer (score 8):

What I know; you can not do this.
Have you though about adding an 'Initialize' method or something similar?

```
public void Initialize<T>(T obj)
{
     object[] attributes = obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute));
     if(attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("The provided object is not serializable");
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but I hope that you get my point.

Comment: If you're going to do a runtime test, the IsDefined method is simpler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I had though of a runtime check, but wanted to use the where constraint. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Jon: You are absolutely right about this. I don't know how I've missed the IsDefined method, but thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Afraid not. Best you can do is a runtime check on [Type.IsSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any class that is serializable, I think you are out of luck.  If you are looking for objects that you have created, you could create a base class that is serializable and have every class you want to support derive from it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I am using a static constructor to check.  It is later but allows you to throw an error at runtime.