# What does the keyword "where" in a class declaration do?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the source code for the MvcContrib Grid and see the class declared as:

```
public class Grid<T> : IGrid<T> where T : class
```

What does the `where T : class` bit do?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221687/can-you-use-where-to-require-an-attribute-in-c

Comment: @Jon Seigel - definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

In this case it means that the generic type (`T`) must be a reference type, that is class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Other constraints are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

You can also constrain the generic type to inherit from a specific type (base class or interface)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with being derived from Object. It can be an interface or delegate, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Another examples would be

```
public A<T> where T : AnInterface
```

where `AnInterface` is a interface class. It means then, that `T` must implement this interface.

These constraints are important, so that the compiler knows the operations which are valid for the type. For example you can not call functions of `T` without telling the compiler what functions the type provides.

Answer (score 3):

From the Docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

where T : class

The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Answer (score 2):

It is a constraint on the type argument which says that T can either be a class or an interface but not an enum or a struct. So T must be a reference type and not a value type.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 1):

It restricts T to be [a reference type, including any class, interface, delegate, or array type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you can apply restrictions to the kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it instantiates your class are called as  [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

E.g : where T : class

Here where `T` is the Type , The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic type constraint. It specifies that the type `T` has to be a reference type, i.e. a class and not a structure.